# Getting return code "127" after execution of program

Tags: cygwin-64

We are Trying to execute a program like ./sample.exe on 64 bit Cygwin. This executable is built with CMake on Cygwin 64 bit.
The Program is not throwing any error or success details. it simply comes out from the running screen without any error and success states.
and we checked output status using "$?" It returns "127" output.

We checked the missing libraries by using "cygcheck sample.exe" and added the required libraries as per the cygcheck report.

**Details:**
$ gcc --version
**gcc (GCC) 11.3.0**
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ld --version
**GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.40**
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.

$ cygcheck --version
**cygcheck (cygwin) 3.4.6**
System Checker for Cygwin
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2023 Cygwin Authors
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Please let me know if you want more details.